# Subqueries in FROM clauses not working anymore with new wampserver version

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

Using *wampServer 3.0.6 + MySQL 5.7.14*, **none** of my subqueries in a FROM clause is working anymore while using *wampServer 2.5 + MySQL 5.6.17* on another pc, it is perfectly working.
Here are 2 examples of these queries among tens of them 
( Please note that in reality, these examples are used as subqueries of larger ones but don't work individually either ) :

**Query 1** :

```
    SELECT rnbr.*
    FROM
        ( 
            SELECT Rct_Pub_Mbr_Id, 
                   COUNT(Rct_Id) AS Nbr 
                   FROM recits 
            WHERE Rct_Rct_Val_Id = 2 AND 
                  Rct_Pub_Mbr_Id = 2 
            GROUP BY Rct_Pub_Mbr_Id 
        ) AS rnbr
```

**Query 2**

```
    SELECT base.*
    FROM 
        (
          SELECT Mbr_Rel_CRel_Id,
                 Mbr_Rel_Mbr_Id_2 
          FROM membres_relations 
          WHERE Mbr_Rel_Mbr_Id_1 = 16 AND 
                Mbr_Rel_Mbr_Id_2 = 2 AND 
                Mbr_Rel_CRel_Id = "BLK" 
        ) AS base
```

On top of that, writing theses queries in phpMyAdmin (4.6.4) SQL tab, I get the following errors ( examples taken from second query )  :

```
. on the line with "(" after the FROM clause :
    . An expression was expected ( close to ( )
    . Unexpected token ( close to ( )
. on the line with SELECT after the "(" :
    . this type of clause has already been analised ( close to SELECT )
. on the line with ") AS base" :
    . Unexpected token ( close to ) )
    . key word not recognized ( close to AS )
    . Unexpected token ( close to base )
```

None of these happens with the former/other versions.

As it is **systematic**, it is **not due to the content of the queries it self** but it looks more like something was "wrong" with the new configuration...

Does anyone have any idea of what could be done ?

Comment: If you check subquery separately is that working?

Comment: @Ikrom ... Yes, they all work without any problem.  Passing from 1 version to another, I did not change anything, anyway... it should still work.

Comment: What if you use simple query for test, like: `select t1.* from (select * from members_relations) as t1;` . Whether the same errors?

Comment: @Ikrom ... I just tried and nothing changes... Exactely the same errors...

Comment: It looks like this particular version of phpmyadmin is pretty broken.  It's ridiculous on a very fundamental level that they have apparently embedded a SQL parser that won't actually send a query to the server if phpmyadmin itself doesn't understand the query... but that appears to be what's happening.  These errors are not from MySQL Server.  Using the `mysql` command line client, you should find that your queries are fine.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot ... In fact, I noticed there was a problem because the site was not working properly in local... meaning that even without phpMyadmin, it does not work.  On the other hand, doing a c/c of the same queries on the distant server, it works...

Comment: It sounds like you may actually have two unrelated problems, then.  What are the real error messages (from MySQL, as captured by the application logs or from the `mysql` cli)?  The errors in the question are not real errors.  They're coming from PMA.  Compare the result of the query `SELECT @@SQL_MODE;`  on the two servers.

Comment: Its a MySQL Server issue. 5.7 is quite different to 5.6 in quite a few ways.

Comment: I dont actually see why you have a sub query anyway in either of those queries

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution !

It was in fact a question of **Wampserver**, **MySQL** and **phpMyadmin** versions.
Here is what to do if it happens to you :

1. Save the directory on wich your programs/sub-directories are 
   ( *c:/wamp/www/your directory* )
2. Export the full content of your database ( SQL mode )
3. Uninstall wampserver and be sure the *c:/wamp directory* doesn't exist anymore
4. Go to [Secondary repository of Wampserver files](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net).
5. Load **Wampserver 3.0.6** ( note that if you're loading the 64 bits version, you should change the proposed directoy to *c:/wamp* )
6. Load **Wampserver update 3.0.9**
7. Load **MySQL 5.6.xx** ( I loaded 5.6.37 )
8. Load a **former version of phpMyadmin** ( I loaded version 4.1.14 wich is the one of my previous configuration )
9. Launch Wampserver
10. [**left-click**] on Wampserver in the taskbar - **MySQL** - **Version** - **5.6.37**
11. [**left-click**] on Wampserver in the taskbar - **MySQL** - **Configuration** - **SQL mode** - select "**none**"
12. [**right-click**] on Wampserver in the taskbar - **Parameters** - Check "**Alias sub-menus**"
13. To launch phpMyadmin, instead of clicling on "**phpMyadmin**", choose "**your aliases**" and then the **phpMyadmin version you want to use**
14. Copy your saved directory ( point 1 ) onto *c:/wamp/www/*
15. Import your tables and their content using the export SQL you did on point 2.
16. Everything should work again !

I know it looks quite tricky but it works...

Good luck !

Comment: Thats not a solution, that is reverting MySQL to an old version

Comment: @ RiggsFolly ... I fully agree with you, but this "solution" was given to me on the Wampserver forum it self... and I said the same to them with as answer : "It is up to the user to check that his queries still work when changing of version and we are not responsible of phpMyadmin; the user should not test queries with it but use his own php to test" ... ( ! )

Comment: @ RiggsFolly ... The question was in french :"Subqueries ne fonctionne plus dans une clause FROM"

Comment: I think that the `SQL mode - select "none"` would have worked on 5.7 as well

Comment: Also not sure why those queries are written as subqueries, they dont appear to need to be

Comment: @RiggsFolly ... For the subqueries utility, you are right, but they are only 2 extracts among tens of them and as used at several places, they are defined in $_SESSION variables wich are "inserted" in other dynamic queries constructors when needed.